# React Leaflet rendering multiple maps

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I'm trying to render a map centered on the user's browser geolocation using the following code:

```js
function ChangeView(props) {
  const map = useMap()
  console.log(props.center) // testing
  map.setView(props.center)

  return null
}

function Map() {
  const [center, setCenter] = React.useState([0, 0])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
      setCenter([pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude])
      console.log([pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude]) // testing
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="map">
      <MapContainer
        center={[0, 0]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: 380, width: 375 }}
      >
        <ChangeView center={center} />

        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The issue is that I get multiple maps render all over the page:
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try `center={center}`

Comment: I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had to import the CSS stylesheet:

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
```